# How do I add permissions to my tomcat.sh?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, touch

I have created a tomcat.sh file so that I can start and stop tomcat via the terminal. I placed the file inside the `/bin` folder and performed `chmod u+x` on it to make it executable.

But then when I try the command `tomcat start` it just gives me the following:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch '/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': Permission denied
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 538: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

I'm a new to Linux. Please help me set up proper permissions for this. If not, then maybe I'll just move my tomcat folder elsewhere.

Comment: First of all, you should place the file in `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/bin`. Also, if the file is called `tomcat.sh`, you won't really execute it when you call `tomcat`, since the name is different. What's the content of your `tomcat.sh` file? Have you tried just running tomcat with `sudo tomcat start`?

Answer (score 1):

Use: `mkdir -p /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/`

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this is probably that you need to start the Tomcat service as root. Try `sudo tomcat start` instead (assuming that `tomcat start` is correct); that will run the starter process as root.

It's either that, or you aren't executing what you think you are. Remember that in Linux, you must give the full name of the file you want to execute; `tomcat` and `tomcat.sh` are distinctly different. This is because unlike on Windows, file extensions in Linux (and other Unixes) are essentially devoid of meaning to the OS.